# WCF - Number of Hit counts by clients

Tags: wcf

How to count the number of hits by each client in WCF. 
Based on the hit count i need to charge amount for each clients. Approaches please.

Some thing like below i need to use, but i'm not sure.

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
 public class serviceclass : Iservice
 {
    // some code…
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your Web service is hosted in a Web environment like IIS.

You could then use the `Application_BeginRequest` in the Global.asax file.

If not possible, you could also develop a HttpModule.

There is also the possibility of using `IDispatchMessageInspector`:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2766957/755977

Answer (score 0):

Simply log each call to a database. Include the method name, date & time, username and IP address called from.

You can then analyse this data to see how much to charge each user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WCF Analytic Tracing with ETW.
Look here for list of events that are generated: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee473461(v=vs.110).aspx
One that might serve your needs is [OperationInvoked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee845496(v=vs.110).aspx) event.
You can use third-party tools like PerfView to analyze these events, or you can create your own tool (use [Microsoft TraceEvent Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent/)).